# Get link from page - python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If we have a link:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="abc">Text</a>
```

How we can take url address http://example.com from this code?
Using selenium webdriver python (other languages are acceptable)

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('abc')` will give Text, not link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`WebElement.get_attribute`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('abc')
href = element.get_attribute('href')
href # => u'http://example.com/'
```

Comment: I was about to give a `beatifulsoup` answer.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, Go ahead.

Comment: it was exactly what i searched for. Thanks @falsetru